# google analytics tag not working in rails 7 app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, ruby-on-rails-7

Hi have a rails 7 application and want to place my google analytics tag js snippet.

What I tried was just adding this script to the application.html.erb, which does not work (probably related to hotwire / turbo)?:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-1234556789"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-123456789');
</script>
```

Comment: If you inspect the view do you see the js in there?  Just want to verify it is on the page but not firing.

Comment: when I inspect its not there.

Comment: ok so you added those lines to `application.html.erb` but it is not showing?  And it doesn't work if you just refresh the page, or do a hard reload of the page?  Since this is a google tracking code I just want to make sure, you did deploy the changed code to the site, correct?

Comment: I added it to application.html.erb, thats correct! The thing is that Rails 7 uses turbo which is why I think it does not work with inline js but thats just a guess.

Answer (score 7):

This method worked for me

In your site html head

```
<script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-111111111" data-turbo-track="reload" async></script>
```

and in the application.js

```
document.addEventListener("turbo:load", function(event) {
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)}
  gtag('js', new Date())
  gtag('config', 'G-111111111', {'page_location': event.detail.url})
}, false)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me.  It would be helpful to add that it is required that you setup Google Tag Manager.  Then add GA to it.  Also Sabrina I believe you'll need to configure tag manager to have two "triggers".  Create a trigger for both Page Views and History Changes.

Comment: Thanks! This works for firebase analytics perfectly. I didn't have to setup anything in GA, nor Tag manager.